# How to get a certain number sequence of rows using mysql and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I get a certain number sequence of rows using mysql and PHP?

For example, I have a table call test1 and need to get first 10 rows (0-9), followed by the next sequence of rows (10-19) with another mysql/php request and so on... In other words, I need to get only 10 rows at a time per mysql php request?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php mysql pagination](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+%5Bmysql%5D+pagination)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `LIMIT` clause in your SQL queries.

What you want is called *[pagination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagination)* - each batch of records is considered a page. You have to somehow (through `session`, or in the link the user clicks) have to hold account for your current page and request for the next like:

```
SELECT .... LIMIT (page_no * batchsize), batchsize
```

[This article](http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/php-tutorial/paging-using-php.aspx) has some clear examples on how to do that. I hope this helps.

PS: please increase your accept ratio - it's the single way of showing your thanks to people who bother help you

Comment: The second argument to `LIMIT` is the number of rows which you'd like to be returned by the query, the above will therefore return more and more rows as `page_no` increases.

A more correct query:

`SELECT ... LIMIT (<page_no> * <batchsize>), <batchsize>`

Comment: yep, you are right refp - thx for pointing that out - I corrected the post

Comment: thanks everyone for your help, this will lead me in the right direction